# How can I implement WCF/OData access as a "paid upgrade" to my ASP.NET site if I want to use AJAX with the same?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wcf, odata, claims-based-identity

Suppose I'm entertaining a business model that offers free access to my propritary data *if* they visit my website.  These users will have advertising subsidize the cost.

Then, for the paid users I want to offer direct raw WCF access to my data as an incentive.  I don't want this available to the freebie users, but at the same time the site is using AJAX to  render the page content.

**The Problem**

As it is today, AJAX and raw WCF access appear identical on-the-wire.  I need to identify what is the source of the traffic is (webpage, or not), and protect my implementation from abuse.

**Possible Solution?**

It may be possible to grab a page variable (within ASP.net/Javascript) and use this as a validation key that is required for non-paid users. I can include this key with every AJAX request.  If this is the best solution, how should I send it from the server to the client?

**Regarding Authentication**

Not sure if this matters, but all users (paid and non-paid) will be authenticated.  A cookie will be stored on the client and will likely be generated by an STS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a generic domain specific cookie for freebie users, this cookie is sent along any ajax request as well, so you can adjust response. No cookie, no response.